# How to handle a long running request in application and allow user to access application without freezing the UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on an application which has front end developed in **MVC with Telerik Kendo UI** components and backend in **.Net Core Web API**.

I have **Export to excel** functionality for a grid. Sometimes user creates a search with certain parameters (city, zipcode, name, etc..) that yields many records to the grid. (eg: **more than 20 thousand records.**)

When I click on Export to excel, **the application is freezing for more than 4 minutes, request is timing out eventually.** During this time, the user is stopped from accessing the application till the request gets completed.

I would like to know if there is any way to note this export to excel request and run it silently in the background and allow the user to access the application without freezing it, waiting for the response.

I looked on how to handle long running tasks and I could see few references like **Parallel request** or **multi-threading requests** which I am not aware of.

Please suggest the best practices on handling long running tasks in the application to maintain better user experience.

**View page:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<myProject.Models.sampleModel>()
                                 .Name("EmployeeGrid")
                                 .AutoBind(false)
                                 .EnableCustomBinding(true)
                                 .NoRecords(c => c.Template("No Record"))
                                 .Columns(columns =>
                                 {
                                    columns.Bound(User => User.FirstName).Title("First Name").Width(100);
                                    columns.Bound(User => User.LastName).Title("Last Name").Width(100);
                                    columns.Bound(User => User.PersonNumber).Title("Person Number").Width(100).;
                                    columns.Bound(User => User.DueDate).Title("Due Date");
                                    columns.Bound(User => User.Name).Title("Name");
                                    columns.Bound(User => User.CreatedBy).Title("Created By").Width(140);
                                 })
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 100% !important;" })
                                .Pageable(c => c.ButtonCount(5).Input(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 50 }))
                                .Sortable()
                                .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true))
                                .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound")
                                )
                                .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
                                .Excel(excel => excel
                                    .FileName("Employees.xlsx")
                                    .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Menu"))
                                    .AllPages(true)
                                )
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                    .Read(c => c.Action("GetEmployeeRecords", "Menu").Data("Manipulation"))
                                )
                                .Deferred()
)
```

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEmployeeRecords([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string empModel, UserProfile userProfile)
{
    List<JsonFormatModel> SearchFilters = new List<JsonFormatModel>();
    SearchFilters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonFormatModel>>(empModel);
    string sort = "";
    int page = request.Page;
    int pageSize = request.PageSize;
    int count = 0;

    if (request.Sorts.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (SortDescriptor sortDescriptor in request.Sorts)
        {
            if (sortDescriptor.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                sort = string.Format("[{0}] ASC", sortDescriptor.Member);
            else
                sort = string.Format("[{0}] DESC", sortDescriptor.Member);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //EF cannot page unsorted data.
        sort = "";
    }

    var searchRequest = new SearchRequest() { SortExpression = sort, PageNumber = Convert.ToString(page), PageSize = Convert.ToString(pageSize), ID = userProfile.ID, SearchFilterModel = SearchFilters.ToList() };

    //Calling API
    var SearchResult = await ApiClientFactory.Instance.PostAsync<SearchResult, SearchRequest>("Menu/GetAllUsers", searchRequest, GetAuthKey());

    var result = new DataSourceResult()
    {
        Data = SearchResult.SearchGridResultDTO, // Process data (paging and sorting applied)
        Total = SearchResult.TotalMatchedCount // Total number of records
    };

    //Return the result as JSON.
    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that exports the grid to Excel?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Please check the code snippets added for reference. 
When button export to excel is clicked, the configured Ajax read call gets fired as the records are many the excel functionality is breaking sometimes, so I am looking for possibilities to run this task in the background and let user interact with application.

Comment: Ouaou! There is some ultra fluent code there! Unfortunately I have nothing to suggest, beyond asking this question in the forums of Telerik (if they have any).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Thanks for your time. Will try my luck. :)